# How do I add line-height to a <select> using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a  element

```
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Now if I add a CSS line-height property to the dropdown, it doesn't work. How would I use jQuery to style this? I prefer not to use plugins, because this is the only styling I wish to apply.

Comment: I think this need to be done in OS's UI settings

Comment: No way to do it cross-browser?

Comment: No. Select boxes have very limited styling possibilities.

Comment: are you sure what you want is not padding-top : 250px on the option tag? line-height is not a valid property for a select. it wont change it.

Comment: Adding padding to an option isn't cross browser..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

$("#dropdown").css("line-height", value)

why do you need to apply a line-height to the dropdown btw?

Comment: That makes no change to the line-height.

I want to add a line-height for visual purposes.

Comment: you want to increase the line-height or the height of the select tag? what value did you put?

Comment: I put 250 px, to test. And I want to increase the line-height.

Comment: try doing it without the space 250px or in single quotes? '250px'